# Why did Aunt Emma specifically mention living through the '60s?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

At Naomi’s wedding scene from *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Jordan meets Emma, Naomi’s aunt, for the first time and expresses his pleasure at finally meeting her. Their conversation also reveals Jordan’s fondness for donuts.

> Jordan: Oh, I... I... Well...
>
> Aunt: **I lived through the '60s**, my dear. Enjoy the day.

Why did Aunt Emma specifically mention living through the '60s?

Comment: You've asked so many questions about this movie and I'm so curious... are you rewatching it every week and finding new things to ask about? Did you take detailed notes of each thing you wanted an answer to and you've been asking them slowly over time? If so, how long is that list?

Comment: Just to be explicit: Jordan does not have a "fondness for donuts". That is a euphemism for cocaine use.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Aunt Emma has spotted that Jordan has cocaine on his nose and makes a joke about it being sugar powder to spare them both the embarrassment.

> As he leans in to hug her, Aunt Emma spots some white powder on the edge of Jordan’s nostril. Deftly, she wipes it off, smiling.
>
> **AUNT EMMA:** *Into the donuts, I see.*
>
> **JORDAN:** *Oh, I’m--- uh...*
>
> Aunt Emma leans in to his ear.
>
> **AUNT EMMA:** *I lived through the 60s, my dear. Enjoy the day.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Wolf of Wall street Script.](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-wolf-of-wall-street-2013.pdf)</sup></sub>

The 1960s were a period of [notable drug-tolerance (and use)](https://news.gallup.com/poll/6331/decades-drug-use-data-from-60s-70s.aspx), especially amongst young people.

Comment: Well certainly, the 1960s had that reputation. Whether there was actually more drug use, or whether it was actually more socially acceptable, than in the 1890s or 1990s is an open question: but yes, that's what the reference means.

Comment: @MichaelKay  I remember the 60s,so I can't have been there :-). (I'm 73)